# Converting cURL request for node js using Request

Tags: node.js, curl, request

This is a simple one I guess :
I would like to make a request on a `Node.js` server as I'm currently doing it with cURL. Whatever I try, I get an error 404 from the server.

Here is my valid cURL command which returns a JavaScript object:

```
curl --data "ajax=1&example=test" http://some-site-example.com
```

After reading cURL manual and Request manual, here is what I tried in `Node.js`:

```
request.post({'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',ajax:'1',example:'test',url:'http://some-site-example.com'}, function(err, result, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err);    
    else console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: is it [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) module??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are wrong for a [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form](https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms). Also, by specifying `form`, it automatically sets the correct `Content-Type`. So try this:

```
request.post({form: {ajax:'1', example:'test'}, url: 'http://some-site-example.com'}, function(err, response, body) {
```

instead of:

```
request.post({'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',ajax:'1',example:'test',url:'http://some-site-example.com'}, function(err, result, body) {
```

Comment: Thank you for both the solution and the link

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, form automatically adds the content-type, [here's the manual](https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms):

```
request.post('http://some-site-example.com', {form: {ajax:'1',example:'test'}}, function(err, result, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err);    
    else console.log(body);
});
```